# Have to use C++ dll to call C# .NET methods?

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I use this way,but there is a problem.
C# dll'namespace is a.b.c.d, when i write [a.b.c.d::className::method] in C++ code,namespace a.b.c.d can't be identifed.
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/695387/Calling-Csharp-NET-methods-from-unmanaged-C-Cplusp

C# dll： vs2017 .Net4.6.2

C++ dll： vs2013 .Net4.6.2

Answer (score 0):

In C++ CLI, you use `::` instead of `.` when accessing managed namespaces. So if it is a static method, then you would call:

```
a::b::c::d::className::method
```